# Maven doesn't run my testng.xml

Tags: java, maven, automation, testng

When i'm running through testng.xml (right click on testng.xml, then run as TestNG) it works fine - 2 of the tests i have there are running, but when i'm running it from Maven (mvn test) it just perform build and doesn't run the tests.
BTW - i noticed that if i have classes with the word Test in them they are running by default on Maven, but this is not good for me since i need the ability to control the tests through the testng.xml file.

this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Group1</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>artifact1</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>




    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.20</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>




    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is my testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite guice-stage="DEVELOPMENT" name="GroupXdefault suite" verbose="0">
    <test name="Default test" verbose ="1">
        <classes>
            <class name="Group1.artifact1.TC1" />
            <class name="Group1.artifact1.TC2" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

Comment: Post the Maven log please.

Comment: First maven-surefire-plugin as dependency is simply wrong. Furthermore using a profile without an id i have my doubts that this will work without error of maven and of course you need to activate any given profile somehow? I'm not sure if this is just typo here....

Comment: i can't post the logs here... getting error that it's too long...

Comment: According to this link there is a need to add surefire dependency: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/surefire-providers/surefire-testng/dependency-info.html

Comment: how can i activate the profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you just remove profile and try with build plugin

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting pluginManagement tag helped.